# I'm trying to put the a defualt logo in WP theme using if, else condition. But doesn't working

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

Here is the code below. I'm trying to put the default logo using PHP conditions in my wp theme. But it's showing an error.  ( Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'get_template_directory_uri' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\law\wp-content\themes\digital-pro\header.php on line 64 )

```
if( has_custom_logo() ){
      the_custom_logo();
   }
   else{
     echo '<img src=" '.get_template_directory_uri().'/img/logo.png" alt="">';
  }
```

Comment: Please check before if condition.

Comment: what need to check before if condition ? Kindly tell me

Comment: @AbdullahAlFaruk Post your entire php file

Comment: which is line 64 in header.php?

Comment: @ChrisBurton  <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                        <?php
                            if( has_custom_logo() ){
                                the_custom_logo();
                            }
                            else{
                                echo '<img src=" '.get_template_directory_uri().'/img/logo.png" alt="">';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </a>

Comment: @Exprator 


echo '<img src=" '.get_template_directory_uri().'/img/logo.png" alt="">';

Comment: This isn't making any sense. There are no syntax errors here. There must be code that you haven't provided that has an issue.

Comment: you need to share your file.

Comment: yes even i checked and it displays the total tag properly, do post the code of the \digital-pro\header.php , and make sure you are putting this code in some other header or not and using digital-pro theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this..

```
if( has_custom_logo() ){
   the_custom_logo();
}
else{ ?>
   <img src=" <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png"        alt="">
<?php }
```